# Is all linear equation with real solution solvable using 3x3 matrix? If not why?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I believe that all 2 variable with enough information could be solved using the matrix

If given:

2x+5y = 11

3x+7y = 20

we could solve this by doing the following:

[[2, 5], [3, 7]] [x, y] =[11,20]

and we can move the like term to one side and got

[x, y] =[11, 20][[2, 5], [3, 7]]<sup>-1</sup>

and after some calculation we arrived at

[x, y] = [23, -7]

however I am not so sure about 3 variable equations because my friend claims this equation have a solution and yet the determinant is 0 and thus is not solvable using matrix

they are:

3x+5y+7z=9491    -eq1

5x+7y+9z=12233    -eq2

7x+9y+11z=14975    -eq3

where:

x=13,
y=27,
z=1331

is there something that I am missing or is it like what my friend is saying that the matrix has a limitation when solving linear equation?

Comment: How would you solve $2x+4y= 9,$ and $4x + 8y= 18$?  (the second is an integer multiple of the first, hence Infinite solutions.)  How would you solve $2x + 3y =10,$ and $4x +6y =10$  (equivalent to $2x+3y= 5$)?  There are no solutions, because the equations are inconsistent..  So a system of equations is not necessarily going to give a unique solution for each variable.

Comment: @amWhy I see what trick my friend had play on me now. when eq3-eq2 it will produce the same coefficient of eq2-eq1 and thus infinite amount of solution and thus his solution is just one pair of valid solutions.

Comment: Determinant is not zero for the given $3×3$ system.

Comment: @amWhy maybe you wanted to address your message to another user? I muscalculated the determinant (it is really zero), but I didn´t claim the rest of what you´re pointing out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every system of linear equations can be expressed as a matrix equation. In general, the following two are equivalent:

$$\left. \begin{eqnarray}
a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 + \ldots + a_{1n} x_n & = & b_1 \\
a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 + \ldots + a_{2n} x_n & = & b_2 \\
& \cdots \\
a_{m1} x_1 + a_{m2} x_2 + \ldots + a_{mn} x_n & = & b_m
\end{eqnarray} \right\} \iff
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \ldots & a_{2n} \\
&& \ddots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \ldots & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_m \end{bmatrix}$$

We would often write the right-hand side as $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, where $A$ is the matrix with all the coefficients, $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector of unknowns and $\mathbf{b}$ is the vector of values on the right-hand side of the equality.

Also, one of the following statements will be true for any such system:

1. There is a unique solution for $\mathbf{x}$ in terms of the $A$ and $\mathbf{b}$;
2. There is *no* valid solution; or
3. There are an infinite number of valid solutions.

To figure out which one of these is the case, you need to know whether you have exactly enough information to "undo" the matrix multiplication or not. If $m = n$, i.e. you have an equal number of equations and unknowns, then the following statements are equivalent:

1. The system has a unique solution;
2. The matrix $A$ is invertible;
3. The [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of $A$ is non-zero;
4. The rows of $A$ are *linearly independent*, meaning that none of the rows $a_{i \cdot}$ can be written in terms of the other rows as $c_1 a_{1 \cdot} + c_2 a_{2 \cdot} + \ldots + c_m a_{m \cdot}$.

In other words - if you have 3 equations in 3 unknowns, and if you can't combine two of the equations to get something that has the same coefficients as the third one, then there is definitely exactly one solution to all the equations, and if you know how to invert a 3x3 matrix then you can find it by writing $\mathbf{x} = A^{-1} \mathbf{b}$.

However, if $A$ is not invertible (either because its determinant is zero or because it's not even square), then you can't directly tell whether you're in case 2 (no solutions) or 3 (infinite solutions) without some extra work which basically boils down to:

1. Remove all redundancy from the system;
2. Do you have any contradictory information left? If yes, then there are no solutions, if no, there are infinitely many solutions.

For example, if you have $x + 2y = 4$ and $3x + 6y = 12$, then we can take $\mbox{Eqn 2} \rightarrow (\mbox{Eqn 2} - 3 \times \mbox{Eqn 1})$ which leaves $0 = 0$ (meaning that the second equation was redundant to the first), and we're left with a single equation in two variables with infinitely many solutions, including $(2, 1)$, $(4, 0)$, $(5, -\frac{1}{2})$ and so on.

On the other hand, if we have $x + 2y = 4$ and $3x + 6y = 13$, then doing $\mbox{Eqn 2} \rightarrow (\mbox{Eqn 2} - 3 \times \mbox{Eqn 1})$ leaves us with $0 = 1$, a clear contradiction, so our system has no solutions.

Notice that in both cases $\det \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 6 \end{bmatrix} = 1 \times 6 - 2 \times 3 = 0$, which is why we're in this situation in the first place.

There are ways to do these operations using matrices, including something called [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), but I won't go into the details here.

Comment: This answer is very insightful! thank you so much not only did you only answer my problem which is can i solve a system of equation of 3 variable using matrix but also explain how there is 4 condition that is connected/equivalent to  to each other. However I don't understand this point "The rows of A are linearly independent, meaning that none of the rows ai⋅ can be written in terms of the other rows as c1a1⋅+c2a2⋅+…+cmam⋅." What is c1, c2 c3... Do you mean b1,b2,b3....?

Comment: This does not address "method" but Wolfram Alpha offer solutions 
[here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+3x%2B5y%2B7z%3D9491%2C++++5x%2B7y%2B9z%3D12233%2C++7x%2B9y%2B11z%3D14975+over+integers).

Comment: $c_1, c_2, \ldots$ are *any* possible values. So I mean that no matter how you try to write, for example, row 1 as a combination of the other rows of the matrix, you will fail. Same for row 2, row 3, and so on. On the other hand, if you can find that (for example) three times row 1 plus seven times row 2 gives you row 3, then those rows are linearly *dependent*.